# Kafka messages over rest api

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, vert.x

we currently have a library which we use to interact with kafka. but we planning to develop this library into a separate application. Other applications will send kafka messages using rest endpoint. Planning to use vert.x in this application to make it non-blocking and fast. Is it a good strategy. My concern 1) http will make it slower compared to TCP of kafka 2) streaming may not be possible 3) single point of failure
But being separate application - release management, control and support will be lot easier than currently. 
Is it good strategy and has someone done like this before? Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try Confluent Rest proxy https://www.confluent.io/product/compare/

Comment: @Jacky confluent proxy is rest access to kafka. I don't think that is what we need as library has lot of functionality like storing some data on s3 etc.

Comment: If you need to store data in S3, you would also use Kafka Connect (Confluent also provides that connector). You wouldn't want to couple that process with a REST endpoint that should just be a Kafka producer. Confluent's recommendations are generally only use a REST proxy if you explicitly need to limit Kafka access via that single process, or you have no clients that offer native clients

Answer (score 0):

Your consideration for going with HTTP/ TCP will depend on the number of applications that will be talking to your service. Let's say there is an IOT device that is sending lots of messages continuously, then using HTTP will be expensive and it will increase latency. Since HTTP connection establishment is an expensive operation.

Now, consider the case where you have a transactional system that is sending transaction events as they commit to your database then the rate of messages will be lower I assume, then it makes sense to use HTTP there.

It will depend on the rate of messages that your service will receive, that will decide the way you want to take.

Now, for your current approach of maintaining a library, it is a good way to maintain consistency across the organisation as long as the library is maintained and users of your library constantly update as and when you make changes to your library. It also has the advantage of not maintaining separate infrastructure/servers since your code will run in your users' application.